# What are some useful databases for performance-enhancing compounds?

Tags: drug-design

What are some useful databases for performance-enhancing compounds?

I've been interested in cognitive enhancers etc.

Comment: +1. I joined the others in voting to close because I thought you were asking something that could be better answered at Physical Fitness SE, but it seems you want to do computational modeling and want a database of geometries for performance enhancing drugs, like we can find for drugs against malaria?

Comment: @NikeDattani Yes.

Answer (score 4):

#### [DrugBank](https://go.drugbank.com/)

- Knowledge base for drug interactions, pharmacology, chemical structures, targets, metabolism, & more. Download limited datasets, free for academic & non-commercial researchers. 500,000 drugs & drug products.

#### [Zinc](https://zinc.docking.org/)

- Free database of commercially-available compounds for virtual screening. ZINC contains over 230 million purchasable compounds in ready-to-dock, 3D formats. ZINC also contains over 750 million purchasable compounds you can search for analogs in under a minute.

#### [The Cambridge Structural Database (CSD)](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/solutions/csd-core/components/csd/)

- Organic crystal structures include: Drugs and pharmaceuticals.     Agrochemicals. Pigments. Explosives. Protein ligands.
- Metal-Organic crystal structures include: Metal Organic Frameworks (MOFs). Models for new catalysts. Porous frameworks for gas storage. Fundamental chemical bonding.